# How to cancel pending Api requests automatically in redux toolkit query

Tags: react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am using `redux toolkit query` Now I am calling an API and this Api can trigger multiple times , now I want suppose if there are two calls,  suppose first call takes time and second call resolves before ist call,  I want to cancel first call if 2nd resolve before ist. But if they resolve in order then I don't want to do anything.